# How can I test my scripts with dynamic jest test?

Tags: jestjs

I'm facing a problem where I have a test script that I would love to use dynamic testing.
This is so far my script:

[image]

The output for details is an array with objects like:

[image]

My question is how can I test my case like:

```
      **expect(......).toBe(expectedMessage)**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after taking a break to clear my head, I have manage to resolve this problem on a easy way :

1. Convert details array into object
2. Compare the expected result with expectedMessage

here is the final result:
[image]

[image]

Hope this solution is helpful and if there are any comments, feel free to drop it because I believe together I can learn from you.

Best regards and let me say: Keep coding!!!